# Build a fat aar which will include other sub modules as jar/aar using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar, android-gradle-2.0

I have a top level android library module (containing res folder) dependent on other library sub modules(no res). I want to build a fat aar of the top level module which should include the jar of the sub modules as well as any other aar dependency which I mention in the build.gradle. Is this possible? how? I can give more info if needed.

Comment: just try this site here.. it contains some steps to build fat aar real time experience...http://androidjavaworld.blogspot.in/2016/12/android-studio-222-repeated-error_94.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `fat-aar.gradle` script that does exactly this:
https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar

Comment: Unfortunately this project is no longer maintained - it is incompatible with latest android gradle plugin